# How to Set Dynamic Width UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I build an iOS application, and I'm using Collection View with Collection View Cell. I already set the Collection View constraint to the main view. but, however if I run the application, it give different result. Even, in the iPhone 5 version, the content was overlapping the screen width.

Please look at the screen shot below

[image: iphone 5 version]

The content of the collection view was overlapping the screen size. Please compare with the iPhone 7 and 7plus version below

[image: iphone 7 version]

and this is the iPhone 7p version

[image: iphone 7p]

I already tried to set the specific constraint for top, left, bottom, right, but it give no result. This is my storyboard of the view controller

[image: storyboard]

I search on entire site, but I only found how to set the dynamic height, not the width. I only want to set the dynamic width, because the content height was constant. Could anyone give me any advice?

Note : this is my collection view code (maybe someone want to look)

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds


    return CGSize(width: collectionPromo.bounds.size.width, height: collectionPromo.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize.height);
}
```

I tried to set the dynamic width that code (I found in the internet)

NOTE: it's not the image view content mode problem, because the one that overlaps were the entire content (include label) not only the image view
this is my collection view code

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellPromo", for: indexPath)

    var labelPromo = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
    labelPromo.text = list[indexPath.row].Period

    var imagePromo = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIImageView
    let promimg = try? UIImage(data: Data(contentsOf: URL(string: list[indexPath.row].ImageUrl)!))
    imagePromo.image = promimg!
    imagePromo.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit
    //imagePromo.layer.masksToBounds = true
    imagePromo.clipsToBounds = true


    cell.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    cell.layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    //cell.layer.contentsScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25
    cell.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
    cell.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: cell.bounds).cgPath
    cell.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor


    return cell
}
```

Comment: What are the constraints on the image view?

Comment: look at the storyboard (right section)

Comment: I think you fixed width of collectionview for iphone 7 so it is overflow in iphone 5

Comment: @PhuDuy how to make it dynamic? I just set the top, left, and right constraint

Comment: @christ2702 you try change view as to iphone 5, i see a constraint relate to width in your image

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can add background color to your image view . And see it in aspect fit. You need add images in your app which are not in portrait mode. Also you need add constraints so no images extend the bound.

Simple advice is to debug the reason why it streches on that particular device ?
Follow three steps
1) use background color

2) constraints on imageview

3) play with image aspect ratio

```
    Try this - let IS_OS_8_OR_LATER = 
    Float(UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion) >= 8.0

   let IS_IPHONE = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Phone

   let IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6 = (IS_IPHONE && 
   UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 667.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && 
    UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale == UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

let IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6 = (IS_IPHONE && 
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568.0 && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && 
 UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale > 
UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

let IS_STANDARD_IPHONE_6_PLUS = (IS_IPHONE && 
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 736.0 )

let IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS = (IS_IPHONE && 
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 667.0  && IS_OS_8_OR_LATER && 
UIScreen.mainScreen().nativeScale < UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

if IS_ZOOMED_IPHONE_6_PLUS {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: the iPhone 7plus version, the is additional space in left and right of the collection view cell

Comment: Its simple issue layout with image aspect issue. Just try to add few more constraints and play with aspect fill and fit.

Comment: Updated my answer please check

Comment: I already try your advice, but it give no different result. because the UILabel below the image is also overlapping. please remember that I use collection view cell not only image view

Comment: I am sure that it is autolayout issue. But if you believe you have done everything then last thing , I would suggest for you is this piece of code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151582/discussion-between-cole-and-christ2702).

Answer (score 0):

Use collectionView Methods to set Edge of CollectionView. Collection View automatic calculate its dynamic width.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
{
    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
}
```

Or U can use this.

But try to put following code inside viewDidLoad():

```
collectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
```

This will add padding to every side of the collectionView.